# IE8 Compatibility View issues

Tags: internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I have the IE7 emulater tag in a jsp layout. But when I bring up the page, it defaults to the IE8 view until the user clicks the Compatibility View button. I don't want the user to have to click the button to launch compatibility mode. **Is there a way to force IE7 Emulation on pageLoad?** I'd even like to disable the button (or any potential to toggle between IE8 standard mode/IE7 view). Thanks!

//sw

Update: Now the button seems to have disappeared entirely, but still defaults to IE8 standards. Where did it go?! The toolbar context menu has it as selected, but the tools dropdown menu has it grayed out. For my purposes, it is unacceptable for the user to have to use the developer tools or even click the button to trigger emulation, but I don't know why the button disappeared anyway...

Update #2: Seems a Group Policy patch disabled the button from the browser... solves the disappearing button issue, but the original problem remains: How can I force IE7 emulation on pageLoad of an IE8 browser?